# 1s complement representation for integer variable in C

Tags: c, ones-complement

I am new to C so I got confused with this code.
I wanted to know how one's complement will work for integer variable

Code:

```
int f = 45;
printf("Value of %d is = %d",f,~f);
```

now output is coming as

> "Value of 45 is = -46"

My question is: this is integer variable and in my compiler int is of 4 bytes i.e. 2^32

so that means it will be represented in machine as

```
4294967296  . . . . . . . 32 16 8 4  2 1

0                          1   0 1 1  0 1
```

right? or it will be represented till first 8 bits?

If represented till 32 bits then number between '32' bit and '4294967296'  will be 0 right because this is 4 bytes integer and this needs to be represented this way right?

> What about representation of number, I need some reference point then.
> I will research on my own, Assume int is of 4 bytes, if I write int a
> = 3; will it be represented with 8-bits representation 00000011 or with  00000000000000000000000000000011 and if I write int a = 257,
> will it be represented with 0000000100000001 or with 00000000000000000000000100000001
> Please give me some hint or explanation on this?

Then when we're going to calculate ~ 1s complement, we're going to invert the values of bit, thus in this case bits between 32 and 4294967296 will be turned to 1 from 0 ? If so, then it's going to become some big value? How was this -46 calculated here?

Comment: The computer you're running the program on uses two's complement, like most computer nowadays.

Comment: Ok, But what about representation of number, I need some reference point then I will research on my own, Assume int is of 4 bytes, if I write int a = 3; will it be represented with 8-bits representation 00000011 or with  00000000000000000000000000000011

and if I write int a = 257, will it be represented with 0000000100000001

or with 00000000000000000000000100000001

Please give me some hint or explanation on this?

Comment: The most significant bit is not `4294967296` it is actually the sign bit of the signed type `int` and for an `unsigned int`, it represents `2147483648`

Comment: An int is 32 bits regardless of the value assigned. So 3 will still be a 32-bit number even though it can fit in one byte.

Comment: It is time to forget about this by now. C23  and C++23 will both only allow two's complement, because nothing else is used in practice. So if you don't fully understand 1s complement, that's fine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say, `~f` results in the ["one's complement"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement) value of `f`, i.e. looking at the binary representation, `~f` will flip all bits of `f`. Hence, `~` is usually referred to as the "bitwise NOT" operator. On a system where `int` is 32 bits, all values of that type are represented using the full 32 bits, regardless of the value. Hence, e.g. "3" is represented as `00000000 00000000 00000000 00000011` and thus "~3" is `11111111 11111111 11111111 11111100`.

Your computer, like most modern computers does not use "one's complement" for representing negative integers. It uses ["two's complement"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) instead. Thus, when printing the value of `~f` it will print the value which the bit pattern of `~f` represents in "two's complement", not "one's complement".

The rule is quite simple. If `f` is a positive integer, then in "two's complement":

```
-f == ~f+1
```

or, equivalently:

```
~f == -(f+1)
```

Thus in this case, where `f` = 45, we get `~f` = -(45+1) = -46.

Comment: I didn't completely understood but I will look into this once attain that much understanding. thanks

Comment: @user3737377 You are welcome. I recommend the linked Wikipedia pages for details.

Answer (score 0):

printing the result in hex may give you some idea about ones-complement

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int f = 45;
    printf("int: %d int1s : %d \n",f,~f);
    //since each byte is two hex digits, 4 bytes correspond to 8 digits
    printf("hex : %08x , 1scomp : %08x \n",f,~f);
    return 0;
}
```

will result in the below output:
ones-complement of each digit ,in hex notation, should add-up to 15(0xF) as in this example.

```
int: 45 int1s : -46 
hex : 0000002d , 1scomp : ffffffd2
```

Answer (score 0):

> What about representation of number, I need some reference point then
> I will research on my own, Assume int is of 4 bytes, if I write int a
> = 3; will it be represented with 8-bits representation 00000011 or with 00000000000000000000000000000011 and if I write int a = 257, will
> it be represented with 0000000100000001 or with
> 00000000000000000000000100000001 Please give me some hint or
> explanation on this?

257 cannot be stored in 8bits so it will be `00000001`. So your logic is wrong as 8 bit byte cannot magically become 16 bits.

To be more complicated the 32bit number will not be stored (on most systems as they use [little endian notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)) the way you show. It will be:

```
byte 0   byte 1   byte 2   byte 3
00000001 10000000 00000000 00000000
```

For one's complement artithmetics in C language (when using standard operators) you need to change the computer to for example PDP-1. [image]
You will be even able to play the Spacewars game!
[image]